# Max size of ScriptBlock / InitializationScript for Start-Job in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, parameter-passing, jobs, limits

When you start a new job with `Start-Job`, you can pass it a `ScriptBlock` and a `InitializationScript` for example:

```
Function FOO {
  Write-Host "HEY"
} 
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {FOO} -InitializationScript {
  Function Foo { $function:FOO }
} | Wait-Job | Receive-Job
```

There seems to be a limit to the size of the initialization script you can pass, if it is too big then you get an error such as

```
[localhost] An error occurred while starting the background process. Error
reported: The filename or extension is too long.
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (localhost:String) [], PSRemotingTransportException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : -2147467259,PSSessionStateBroken
```

Behind the scenes, PowerShell is creating a new process and passing `InitializationScript` as a Base64 encoded command line parameter.

According to the Win32 [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) function, the max size of the command ine is 32,768 characters. So obviously if your Base64 encoded `InitializationScript` is getting near this size then you will probably get an error.

I haven't yet found a limit for the size of the `ScriptBlock` parameter. Can someone confirm that there is no limit?

I assume that there is no limit because it looks like the `ScriptBlock` is transmitted to the child process via standard input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess was correct.

**PowerShell translates a `Start-Job` call into a PowerShell CLI call behind the scenes** (to [`powershell.exe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) for Windows PowerShell, and to [`pwsh`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pwsh) for PowerShell (Core) 7+), that is, **it achieves parallelism via a *child process* that the calling PowerShell session communicates with**, using the standard in- and output streams:

- Because the **`-InitializationScript`** script block is translated to a Base64-encoded string representing the bytes of the UTF-16LE encoding of the block's string representation, which is passed to the CLI's `-EncodedCommand` parameter, its max. length is **limited by the overall length limit of a process command line**.

  - That limit is **32,766 characters** (Unicode characters, not just *bytes*), because a terminating NUL character is required in the underlying WinAPI call (to quote from the [`CreateProcess()` WinAPI function documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createprocessa?redirectedfrom=MSDN) you link to: "The maximum length of this string is 32,767 characters, including the Unicode terminating null character").
  - Note that the full path of the PowerShell executable is included in this limit, in double-quoted form (see below), and it really is the entire resulting command line that matters; therefore, given that PowerShell (Core) 7+ can be installed in any directory, its installation location has an effect on the effective limit, as does the length of the path of the current directory (see next point).
  - In **Windows PowerShell**, whose location is fixed, and whose CLI parameter values are of fixed length in the invocation (see below), this leaves **32,655** characters **for the Base64-encoded string** (32766 - 111 characters for the executable path and fixed parameters and the `-EncodedCommand`  parameter name); while **similar**, no fixed number can be given for **PowerShell (Core) 7+**, due to differing install locations and the length of the `-wd` (working-directory) argument depending on the current location.
  - **Base64-encoding** the bytes of a UTF-16LE-encoded strings results in a **ca. 2.67-fold increase in length**, which*makes the **max. length of a script block passed to `-InitializationScript`  **12,244 characters**<sup>[1]</sup> for **Windows PowerShell**; for **PowerShell (Core) 7+**, it'll be **slightly lower**, depending on the installation location and the length of the current directory's path.
- By contrast, the **`-ScriptBlock` argument**, i.e. the operation to perform in the background, is **sent via *stdin*** (the standard input stream) to the newly launched PowerShell process, and therefore has ***no* length limit**.

For instance, the following [`Start-Job`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/start-job) call:

```sh
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { [Environment]::CommandLine } -InitializationScript { 'hi' > $null } | 
  Receive-Job -Wait -AutoRemoveJob
```

reveals that the background-job child process was launched as follows, when run from Windows PowerShell:

```sh
"C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -Version 5.1 -s -NoLogo -NoProfile -EncodedCommand IAAnAGgAaQAnACAAPgAgACQAbgB1AGwAbAAgAA==
```

As you can see, the `-ScriptBlock` argument's text is *not* present in the resulting command line (it was sent via stdin), whereas the `-InitializationScript` argument's is, as the Base64-encoded string passed to `-EncodedCommand`, which you can verify as follows:

```sh
# -> " 'hi' > $null ", i.e. the -InitializationScript argument, sans { and }
[Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetString([Convert]::FromBase64String('IAAnAGgAaQAnACAAPgAgACQAbgB1AGwAbAAgAA=='))`)
```

As for the other parameters:

- `-s` is short for `-servermode`, and it is an undocumented parameter whose sole purpose is to facilitate background jobs (communication with the calling process via its standard streams); see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45335547/45375) for more information.
- `-Version 5.1` applies only to Windows PowerShell, and isn't strictly necessary.
- `-NoLogo` is also not strictly necessary, because it is *implied* by the use of `-EncodedCommand` (as it would be with `-Command` and `-File`).
- In PowerShell (Core) 7+, you'd also see a `-wd` (short for: `-WorkingDirectory`) parameter, because background jobs there now sensibly use the same working directory as the caller.

---

<sup>[1]
`[Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::Unicode.GetBytes('x' * 12244)).Length` yields `32652`, which is the closest you can come to the `32655` limit; an input length of `12245` yields `32656`.</sup>

Answer (score 0):

the script block actually have limit. and you can run command with scriptblock with 3 way :

```
$scriptblock = '
get-help
get-command
dir
get-help *command*
get-command *help*
'

iex $scriptblock
```

or use it :

```
$scriptblock = {
get-help
get-command
dir
get-help *command*
get-command *help*

}

Start-Process powershell.exe -ArgumentList "Command $scriptblock"
```

or use this :

```
Start-Process powershell {iex  '
get-help
get-command
dir
get-help *command*
get-command *help*


'
}
```

the limit of script that can pass to powershell.exe is **12190 bytes**.
but for script i never get limit from powershell more than 4000 line code.

Comment: Do you have any evidence that there is no limit, or a reason that there is no limit?

Comment: @BobMortimer: i write about 4000 line code in script block the limit of your text or script block depend your hardware like ram .. .

Comment: @BobMortimer : but when u pass script you can just 12190 bytes pass to powershell.exe

Comment: I don't believe the 12k limit - I was able to pass the full text of John Gay's "The Beggar's Opera" in the ScriptBlock which is around 118k

Comment: @BobMortimer : if you done use .ps1 file you can do it easy just pass the script block directly to powershell you pass even more than 118 k.

Comment: My question was whether there is a limit, and if so what it is. I'm not asking about how to work around a limit (if any). You seem to think there is a limit - where did the 12k figure come from?

Comment: [`Invoke-Expression` (`iex`) should generally be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375). When you do need to use it (which is rare), it takes a _string_, which is indeed what you're using in the first snippet, despite calling the variable `$scriptblock`. While you are technically creating a script block, via a `{ ... }` literal, in the second snippet, it becomes a string in your `Start-Process` call - so there's no reason to create a script block to begin with. The same applies to the third snippet.